# Compare two arrays using include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two arrays:

```
@all_genres = [#<Genre id: 1, name: "Action", created_at: "2013-03-01 07:44:51", updated_at: "2013-03-01 07:44:51">,
               #<Genre id: 2, name: "Adventure", created_at: "2013-03-01 07:44:51", updated_at: "2013-03-01 07:44:51">,
               #<Genre id: 3, name: "Animation", created_at: "2013-03-01 07:44:51", updated_at: "2013-03-01 07:44:51">]

@genres = ["Action", "Animation"]
```

I am trying to find the `Genre.id` from `@genres` compared to the `@all_genres` table.  For example my result should be:

```
@genre_ids = [1, 3]
```

I have tried this:

```
@all_genres.each do |g|
  if g.name.include?((@genres.each {|g| g}).to_s)
    @genre_ids << g.id
  end
end
```

I tried this in my console and it seemed to work but when I put it into my app it returns:

```
@genre_ids = []
```

Comment: `g.name` is a `String`. Did you really mean to call `String#include?`, or did you mean to call `Array#include?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could try this one-liner:

```
@genre_ids = @all_genres.select{|g| @genres.include? g.name }.map(&:id)
```

Comment: While this is strictly what they asked for, it does require loading all the genres from the database where the operation could be performed there instead.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but unless your data is already available as plain arrays, do consider the railsism as demonstrated in the other answers. I'd go with `Genre.where(..)` if I knew for there was a table like that.

Answer (score 6):

A more rail-sy version:

```
@genre_ids = Genre.where(name: @genres).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Some documentation are also good to have in hands. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're populating your `@genres` array with a call to `Genre.all`.

You could simply do something like this:

```
Genre.where("name IN (?)", %w[name action]).collect { |x| x.id }
```

If you want to retrieve the `ids` for the Genres with those names.

Comment: `"name IN (?)"` is case sensitive.